# display data in option selected

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

***guys, need help please. i'm now working my portfolio using codeigniter and i'm stock in the edit form modal because i want to display option is selected with data from mysql but it doesn't.***

Here is my Controller:

[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lD9Jk.png)

Here is my Model:

```
    <?php
    
    class User_model extends CI_Model {
    
    function session_user_info($session_user){
    function get_multi_item_data_inserted($session_ref_id){
        $output = '';
    
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('incident_cat');
        $q_storeCode = $this->db->get();
        $incident = $q_storeCode->result();
    
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('store_code');
        $q_storeCode = $this->db->get();
        $store_code = $q_storeCode->result();
    
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->order_by('ref_id','DESC');
        $this->db->join('incident_cat','item_details.incident_type = incident_cat.incident_id');
        $this->db->join('store_code','item_details.store_code = store_code.store_id');
        $this->db->where('ref_id_num', $session_ref_id);
        $this->db->from('item_details');
        $get_query = $this->db->get();
    $output .= '<table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
                    <thead class="bg-primary">
                        <th class="text-center">Store</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Action</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>';
                    if($get_query->num_rows() > 0){
                        foreach ($get_query->result() as $row):
        $output .= '<tr>
    <td class="text-center">'.$row->store_area.'</td>
    <td class="text-center">'.'
                            <a href="#editItemDataForm'.$row->ref_id.'" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                                </a>
                            <button onClick="del_Data('.$row->ref_id.')" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                            </button>
                        '.'</td>
                    </tr>';
    $output .= '<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal" id="editItemDataForm'.$row->ref_id.'" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" id="close_btn">&times;</button>
                                    <h5 class="modal-title"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span> <b>Edit item(s) </b></h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                <form method="post" class="form-vertical addform">
    <div class="form-group">
                                    <div id="edit_store_code_err">
                                        <label for="store_code">* Store code:</label>
                                        <select type="text" name="edit_store_code" id="edit_store_code" class="form-control input-sm">
                                            <option value="">--- Select store code---</option>
                
                        ';
```

//i'm stock here//

```
foreach ($store_code as $rows){
                    $output .= '<option value="'.$rows->store_id.'"'.if($rows->store_id == $row->store_code)."selected".'>'.$rows->description.' - '.$rows->code.'
                                </option>';
                                
                                /*if($rows->store_id == $row->store_code){
                    $output .= '<option value="'.$rows->store_id.'" selected>'.$rows->description.' - '.$rows->code.'
                                </option>';
                                }*/
                                }
                    $output .= '</select>
                                        <p class="text-danger" id="edit_store_code_error_msg"></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>';
                        endforeach;
                    }else{
        $output .= '<tr>
                        <td class="text-center text-danger" colspan="6"><b> ***** Table is empty ***** </b></td>
                    </tr>';
                    }
        $output .= '</tbody>
                </table>';
    
        return $output;
    }
    ?>
```

Please help guys.

thanks in advance guys.

[Display Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAwsq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this -

```
$output .= '<option value="'.$rows->store_id.'"'.if($rows->store_id == $row->store_code)."selected".'>'.$rows->description.' - '.$rows->code.' </option>';
```

You should use it in the below manner -

```
$selected = ($rows->store_id == $row->store_code) ? 'selected' : '';
$output .= '<option value="'.$rows->store_id.'" '.$selected.' >'.$rows->description.' - '.$rows->code.'</option>';
```

It will first set the `selected` attribute according to condition and then assign it to the select option.

Comment: Thank you so much brother. It's working now. Thanksbagain for the idea.

Comment: Welcome, Bro. Could you please upvote and approve the answer?